# how to pass selected checkbox values from child to parent in lwc using queryselector

Tags: lightning-web-components

html

```html
<lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group"
              data-id="check-box-group"
              label="Checkbox Group"
              options={options}
              value={selectedValues}
              onchange={handleChange}>
</lightning-checkbox-group>
```

js

```js
handleGenerate(event){
    const searchKey = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="search-key"]').value;
    // const workItemType = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="check-box-group"]').value;
}
```

Comment: Your markup uses handleChange, your JS uses handleGenerate. Either you have a copy-paste issue, or you simply didn't call the right method, which would be the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,  you are invoking a handler method when your checkbox-group changes, in return, you are querying the element (from the parent) which is `lightning-checkbox-group` to get the value.

The lwc documentation for the [checkbox-group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example) is very precise on how you can get the value, so, I am not sure what it is you are attempting to do.

your handleChange method shoud get the value using the passed event as follows:

```
handleChange(e) {
        this.value = e.detail.value;
    }
```

I don't understand why you are attempting to use a querySelector.

Comment: but i was able to pass this from child to parent. below is search text value entered                                                            
const searchKey = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="search-key"]').value

Comment: view updated answer. your post /question remains unclear...

Comment: thanks mate. this is how i got the values